# IBM WebSphere Application Server - Auditing the security

Tags: ibm-was

**The summary of the security auditing is generating HTML report from binary audit log after enabling the security auditing and some configurations; but the generated HTML report is not completed(full information) and not meaningful.**

> What i mean is for example when i created a user, it's not audited.
>   When i gave it some roles; these actions have been audited but unclear
>   way.

I have two questions:

- Does not it audit each action that the user do it like create/delete user.?
- Is there a way to format that HTML report to be clear and meaningful or Are there extra configurations to generate HTML report or other report to be clear?

Answer (score 1):

***Does not it audit each action that the user do it like create/delete user?***

Auditing is not recording all the user actions.

> The security auditing subsystem has the ability to capture the
>   following types of auditable events:
>
> - Authentication
> - Authorization
> - Principal/Credential Mapping
> - Audit policy management
> - Delegation

For more details see [Auditing the security infrastructure](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_sa_secauditing.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-8-2-33-5&lang=en)

***Is there a way to format that HTML report?***
There is no way to provide format of that HTML report by default. You may only specify what will be in the report using report mode were valid values include *basic*, *complete*, or *custom*. See [binaryAuditLogReader command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_7auditReader.html?lang=en) for more details.

If you need custom formatting you may need to implement your own audit service provider. For more info see here:

- [Configuring a third party audit service providers](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/info/iseries/ae/tsec_sa_config_asp_3rdparty.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.0.0%2F2-8-32-5-4&lang=en)
- [Example: Base Generic Emitter Interface](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rsec_sa_emitter_interface.html?lang=en)